# How to set Aliases or VirtualHost to run a laravel project on Apache2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, routes, apache2, virtualhost

I'm starting to learn how to set up a lamp on a vps, and i'm trying to run a laravel project.

This is my 000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Alias /laravelproject /var/www/laravelproject/public
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
```

I'm trying to access using the /laravelproject and it works cause i'm redirected to a login page ip/laravelproject/login (like I set using the middleware for not logged users and it works on my local homestead virtual machine). But i got a 404 file not found error. Not a pretty designed laravel one, but a raw and ugly server error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /laravelproject/login was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at '' Port 80

Of course i don't have any laravelproject.com domain to set up, i want to access it simply with my_server_ip/laravelproject.

How can i set up a virtualhost or an alias to run it with all the routes working?

Comment: If anyone is still looking for an answer for this. sudo a2enmod rewrite fixed my problem and I spent hours looking for that. So this might be your solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try enabling apache mod-rewrite if not enabled yet.

```sh
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure the `/var/www/laravelproject/public` directory is set to `AllowOverride All` (which I believe you have taken care of by setting `/var/www` to All).  Then make sure the `.htaccess` file in your `public` directory is correctly set up: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

this is because Apache is looking for `/public/login/index.html` which is not a file.  Laravel's `.htaccess` redirects these requests appropriately, but it has to be in your public folder and Apache has to AllowOverride

edit:

```
<Directory /var/www/laravelproject/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: the .htaccess is the same as the one you posted. The problem is exactly what you said. I tried to create a folder login inside public with an index.php and that's what it loads

Comment: OK see the edit.  Clearly the public folder isn't allowing override, so put that code in apache config and explicitly allow that folder.

Comment: I tried to edit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

'<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<
<Directory /var/www/laravelproject/public>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>'

Comment: Did you restart apache afterwards?  `service apache restart` I think

Comment: sure. now i'm not sure if i edited the right file or if i should try to write a virtualhost on a different conf file

Comment: Another silly cause of this could be that you haven't enabled mod-rewrite in apache. `sudo a2enmod rewrite`